# Turn off UITableView bottom/top gradient mask on tvOS?

Tags: uitableview, tvos

On tvOS, `UITableView` applies a nice looking gradient mask to the top and bottom of the view.  In most instances this is the desired appearance, but in some cases it is not.  Is there a way to conditionally turn that off?  If there isn't an *official* way of doing this, has anyone found an indirect way of removing that effect?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can disable it with the following:

ObjC:

```
self.tableView.maskView = nil;
```

Swift 4:

```
self.tableView.mask = nil
```

Source: [How to remove UISplitViewController Master Navigation Blur Tint](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24682)

Comment: what if I want to remove just bottom overlay and keep the top one?

Comment: @AydinAngouti you just create a View with the frame of the table view's frame, set user interaction disabled and clear background color, and set it as `maskView`.